# Is this Perl's bug in interpretation?

Tags: perl, variables

```
 11 package C;
 12 $_ = 5;
 13 print "$_\n$C::_\n$::_\n";
```

output:

```
5

5
```

As we know `$_` is a super global variable in Perl,but why the **first** assignment to this variable will cause assignment to `$::_` at the same time?

**UPDATE**

```
package C;
$_ = 5;
print "$_\n$C::_\n$::_\n";
package main;
print "####in main::\n";
$_ = 2;
print "$_\n$::_\n";
package A;
our $_ = 1;
$_ = 4;
print "####in A::\n";
print "$_\n$::_\n$A::_\n";
print "####in B::\n";
package B;
$_ = 3;
print "| $_ | \n
        |$::_ | \n
        |$B::_\n";
```

in the last `print`,you can see that `$_` and `$::_` is different.

```
| 3 |

        |2 |

        |
```

Comment: Regarding your update: i can not reproduce your problem. $::_ is identical to $_ in all cases here. What perl version do you use?

Comment: When using ancient versions of perl you may be interested in reading through the perl deltas first http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html

Comment: `$C::_` in line 3 is undefined. Also `$B::_` in the last line is undefined. At least in perl v5.8.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `$_ = 3;` is treated like `$A::_ = 3;` instead of `$::_ = 3`. This seems to be bug in version 5.8.8.

When run in the debugger, the line

```
our $_ = 1;
```

creates a package variable `$A::_` as can be seen in the debugger.

```
  DB<5> V :: _
$_ = 2
@_ = (
   0  0
   1  '_'
   2  *main::_
   3  0
   4  '-1'
)

  DB<6> V A:: _
$_ = 1
```

the next line `$_ = 4;` modifies `$A::_`.

When the line `$_ = 3;` is executed, the package variable `$A::_` is set. This is also buggy. It should access `$::_`. This is the debugger output at that point:

```
  DB<7> V :: _
$_ = 2
@_ = (
   0  0
   1  '_'
   2  *main::_
   3  0
   4  '-1'
)

  DB<8> V A:: _
$_ = 3
```

I hope this shows what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

`$_` is kept in package `main`. Also, if package name is omitted, the `main` package is assumed. That is, `$::_` is equivalent to `$main::_` (as well as to `$main'_`).

Regarding your update: `$_` is supposed to be `$main::_`. But after the `our`, `$_` is now looking at `$A::_`. This seems to be a bug in Perl 5.8.8.

Comment: That's wrong.The super global `$_` isn't contained in any package.

Comment: I've provided an example to prove that.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `$_` is short for `$::_`, as you've demonstrated.

However, in your part of the code in your update, you've changed what `$_` means by creating a lexical named `$_`. This lexical is being used in the case you are asking about.

`our $x` creates a lexical variable `$x` aliased to the current package's `$x`, except for "super globals". For "super globals", the new variable is aliased to the "super global".

```
>perl5140 -le"package PA; our $x='A'; package PB; $x='B'; print $PA::x;"
B

>perl5140 -le"package PA; our $_='A'; package PB; $_='B'; print $::_;"
B
```

It seems that exception didn't exist in 5.8.

By the way, do you realise that 5.8 and 5.10 are officially end-of-lifed?

Answer (score 2):

`::foo` is equivalent to `main::foo` and `main::` is where punctuation variables as `$_` are stored.